# Surface Mount Springs, how are they called?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, components

We are currently in the process of creating Hardware-Test-Boards where we want to "plug-in" our PCB's and do a couple of tests. Our Boards have a rather complicated shape and are mostly surface mounted. Thus we have a hard and error-prone time to figure out, how to automate our tests due to connectivity issues.

Recently I found something on the Omega2s that would perfectly fit our needs.

[image]

The HDK of the Omega2s features those nifty little springs to plug in the sourface-mounted Omega2s which are holding it snug in place. 
But we are unable to find those Springs on e.g. Mouser and Digikey.

How are they called? Where do I find some?

(We already have a footprint, just one hole and a long-hole).

Comment: I bet onion.io could tell you, and let you know about any special requirements, if any, at the same time.

Comment: @AndrewMorton we already contacted onion.io but they only tell us generic stuff that an engineer will contact us, "soon". A BOM is also not available. At least we found none.

Comment: Those are "spring contacts". I don't know where to buy exactly these, but you can buy them similar things as battery connectors for e.g. the old exchangeable lithium batteries in pre-smart-era phones.

Comment: Do a search for "Pogo Pins"

Comment: [Tag-Connect](http://www.tag-connect.com/EdgeConnectIntro) sells something similar.

Comment: That looks   like a custom spring, and would have to be hand-assembled.   For mass production, elastomer one-dimensional conducting strips, so-called Zebra strips, are often used. <https://www.fujipoly.com/usa/assets/files/Fujipoly%202015%20Zebra%20Catalog%20for%20web.pdf>

Answer (score -1):

Mill-Max (mill-max.com) makes a huge variety of spring-loaded contacts, some forms of which are commonly known as "pogo pins". They come in a variety of shapes, sizes, spring travel, and (most important) shape of the contact end of the pin.  Digikey carries a lot of them.

You'll also need some kind of jig to hold the part under test firmly against the contacts, but presumably you already know this.

Comment: Those are **not** pogo pins.  The question is about the wire looking things around the hole in the pictured PCB.